# Webpack 4 syntax for loaders

Tags: typescript, webpack

In Webpack 4 module rules are used to find certain filetypes and pre-compile them, befor bundling them into an `app.js` file. The syntax in the test-entry though is a bit strange. What type of syntax is that?

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/ts/app.ts'),
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Apart from the `.tsx`, how can the rest be understood, hence the part to the right and to the left of the actual file type search `/\` and `?$/`? Why do I only define to test for `.tsx` files and not for `ts` files? I don't understand the difference between `module.rules.test` and `resolve.extensions`. Could someone please explain?

Comment: text between `/` and `/` is a reguler expression.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

a bit of explanation on `/\.tsx?$/`:  `.` has special meaning in regular expressions, so we escape it `\.` to mean literal dot. `?` means the char before it is optional. `$` means last char in the string. So in effect it means match on any string that ends with `.ts` or `.tsx`.

You should really read the webpack documentation.

Comment: @AviadHadad I am about to do that, though I am new the Webpack. There are a couple of easy introduction tutorials around, but then the next step is to deeply dive into very detailed stuff. Nothing much in between both. Thanks for the link and for unveilling that this is Regex in fact.